# Python 3.3.2 check that object is of type file

Tags: python, file, types, python-3.x

I'm porting from Python 2.7 to Python 3.3.2. In Python 2.7, I used to be able to do something like `assert(type(something) == file)`, but it seems that in Python 3.3.2 this is wrong. How do I do a similar thing in Python 3.3.2?

Comment: FWIW, `type(something) == sometype` is generally frowned upon in favor of `isinstance`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python 3 file objects are part of the [`io` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html), test against [ABC classes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy) in that module:

```
from io import IOBase

if isinstance(someobj, IOBase):
```

Don't use `type(obj) == file` in Python 2; you'd use `isinstance(obj, file)` instead. Even then, you would want to test for the *capabilities*; something the `io` ABCs let you do; the [`isinstance()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) will return `True` for any object that implements all the methods the Abstract Base Class defines.

Demo:

```
>>> from io import IOBase
>>> fh = open('/tmp/demo', 'w')
>>> isinstance(fh, IOBase)
True
>>> isinstance(object(), IOBase)
False
```