# Check if an object is a file in Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, compatibility

Is there a Python 2/3-compatible way of checking whether an object is a file?

I need to check if an object `filehandler` is actually a `file` object.  This code needs to run in both Python 2 and 3.  In Python 2 I could do

```
isinstance(filehandler, file)
```

However [`file` is not part of Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins), so this code raises a `NameError` when run with Python 3.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880992/5031373), in Python 3 `io.IOBase` should be used to check if an object is a file, but Python 2's `file` doesn't subclass `io.IOBase`, so `isinstance(filehandler, io.IOBase)` won't work.

I thought about doing `isinstance(filehandler, (io.IOBase, file))`, but that still gives a `NameError` when I run it with Python 3.

Is there a way to do this that is compatible with both Python 2.7 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the most common way of doing this is to check `hasattr` in Python 3. So, I added a check that will check the version of Python, and depending on that, it will execute the right function.

```
import sys

def isFile(f):
    return isinstance(f,file) if sys.version_info[0] == 2 else hasattr(f, 'read')        

f = open("post.php","r")
print(isFile(f))
print(isFile(10))
```

Alternatively, you can use a `lambda`, but I find it less readable.

```
isFile = lambda f:isinstance(f,file) if sys.version_info[0] == 2 else hasattr(f, 'read')
```

Comment: The point of a `lambda` is that it's an unnamed function, so if you need a named function there's no reason not to use a `def`.  Far clearer and far more readable

Answer (score 1):

This was the workaround I used: at the top of the `.py` file, I added:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    from io import IOBase
    file = IOBase
```

So if Python 3 is being used, set `file` to be `IOBase`.  Now `isinstance(filehandler, file)` will work correctly in Python 3, and for Python 2 it will work just like it always has.

Of course, this solution is extremely hackish and confusing, since it makes it look like `IOBase` is the Python 3 version of `file`, which is not the case.  But it does solve the problem.

Comment: IOBase does not guarantee a file like object see for example

`>>> my_var = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
>>> my_var
<tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x10206e198>
>>> isinstance(z, io.IOBase)
False`

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do something like this

```
try:
    #check in py3
except:
    #check in py2
```

You can add some other error handlers if you want, but that should do.

Comment: I'm sure you meant `except NameError:` instead of a blanket `except:` correct?

Comment: yes that would probably be safer if you're relatively sure that's what you'll get

Comment: It' better to only catch what you know you will get than try to catch everything. If the code threw a `ValueError` because of some other unexpected reason then I imagine the blanket `except` would lead to difficult to debug errors.

Comment: This code block won't work, since using the Py3 check doesn't raise an error in Py2, it just gives the wrong answer. The Py2 and Py3 code need to be switched