# create file object in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have python 2.7 code with creates a builtin file object which return me a file object `<type 'file'>`

```
 file(os.path.join('/tmp/test/', 'config.ini'))
```

Same code i changed in python 3.7 as below it returns `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`

```
 open(os.path.join('/tmp/test/', 'config.ini'))
```

How can i get a file object type in python 3

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880948/python-3-3-2-check-that-object-is-of-type-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use them the exact same way.

```py
file = open(os.path.join("/tmp/test/", "config.ini"))
print(file.read())  # Will print file contents
```

Or use pathlib:

```py
from pathlib import Path
file = Path("/tmp/test") / "config.ini"
print(file.read_text())  # will do the same
```

You're not looking for a file object. You're looking for an object that'll let you read and write files.